Python, Kivy: Why is a second ScreenManager() not working?
Consider the following code:
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.clock import Clock

class MyApp(App):                     
    def build(self):                   
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(EntranceScreen(name="Hi"))
        sm.add_widget(QuestionScreen(name="Question"))
        Clock.schedule_once( MyApp.ClockArg, 5)
        print("done with Function")                #Prints, it works
        return sm
    
    def ClockArg(dt):
        print("5 secs passed")                     #Prints, it works
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(QuestionScreen(name="Question"))
        ScreenManager().current = "Question"      

class EntranceScreen(Screen):
    pass

class QuestionScreen(Screen):
    pass

#The rest of code is insignificant

The Problem I am facing is:
After 5 seconds, ClockArg is getting executed, it prints "5 secs passed". But the screen wont change. That means that the second ScreenManager() is not doing anything. Why? How can I change the code that everything will get executed in build() method but also have a 5 sec delay from the first screen to the second?
Thanks!

The solution is to write the initialization (sm = ScreenManager outside the methods, inside the Class so that all methods have access to the same ScreenManager. Otherwise, there would be multiple ScreenManagers and it would not work).
